# Task内で使用するタイマーがTickしない。

Tags: c#

.Net FrameWork 4.5　にて下記プログラム作成しました。
Taskで実行するとtimerはtimer_Tickにたどり着かず、
そのまま呼び出すとtimer_Tickに行きます。
両者の違いは何故発生するのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
class a
{
     Timer timer = new Timer();
     public a()
     {
          timer.Tick +=  timer_Tick;
     }
     public void Start()
     {
          timer.Interval = 1000;
          timer.Start();
     }
     void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        return;
     }
}

class main
{
     public main()
     {
        a A = new a();
        Task.Run(() => { A.Start(); });  //Tick しない。
        A.Start();  //Tick する。
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

自己解決済みですが、原因説明を。

- `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`はUIスレッド上で実行を開始し、UIスレッド上で呼び出されます。実行したスレッドがUIスレッド出なかった場合は呼び出しようがないため動作しません。
- `System.Timers.Timer`はスレッドプールから呼び出されます。どのスレッドからでも実行可能です。

というわけで質問文のコードに関して言えば、`Task.Run()`から実行する意味はあまりなく、メインスレッドから実行すればいいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Forms.Timerを使用していたことが原因でした。
System.Timers.Timerを使用することでTaskて使用してもTick (Elapsed)することがわかりました。